# Dotnet SSL error between two docker containers

Tags: c#, .net, docker, ssl, docker-compose

I have a problem where I am running several containers using docker-compose for Visual Studio. The containers are hosted on the default network and are reachable from within using `host.docker.internal` on the exposed and mapped ports `42000`, `42001` and `42002`. The problem is when one container (that runs scheduled jobs) wants to call an API in another container through using TLS. I am getting this error in C#:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.'
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

The default development certificates are mounted onto the containers using

```
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https
```

in `docker-compose.override.yml`.

This is the `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  portalpro:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}portalpro
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/PortalProV2/Dockerfile

  external-web-api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}external-web-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/PortalPro.External.WebApi/Dockerfile

  scheduler:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}scheduler
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Scheduler/Dockerfile
```

This is the `docker-compose.override.yml`

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  portalpro:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      # other app config values
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
    ports:
      - "40000:80"
      - "42000:443"

  external-web-api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      # other app config values
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
    ports:
      - "40002:80"
      - "42002:443"

  scheduler:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      # other app config values
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets
    ports:
      - "40001:80"
      - "42001:443"
```

This is one of the Dockerfiles, the others are similar:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1.5-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# ENV - some env var setup

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PortalProV2/PortalProV2.csproj", "PortalProV2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "PortalProV2/PortalProV2.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/PortalProV2"
RUN dotnet build "PortalProV2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PortalProV2.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PortalProV2.dll"]
```

I can call the containers from localhost. They can call other trusted services. It's just that docker to docker communication is broken.

I also have mssql running in a docker container, and it is reachable from within using `host.docker.internal,1433`.

I have tried to use openssl to generate a local self-signed certificate with SAN=host.docker.internal and localhost, and then install, trust on the host machine, and also install the certificates to the containers using `update-ca-certificates`, but this failed.

I have also tried to use `dotnet dev-certs` to generate the certificate and trust it, but it's the usual way, and it failed too.

`openssl s_client -connect host.docker.internal:42000` from within the container returns these errors:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 CN = localhost
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = localhost
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
...
```

`curl -X GET https://host.docker.internal:42000/index.html` returns

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to host.docker.internal port 443: Connection refused
root@4b4b805a4250:/app# curl -X GET https://host.docker.internal:42000/index.html
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Docker is running on Windows on WSL2. Linux containers.

Surely there must be something that I am missing, some obvious thing, since all of the solutions I am finding don't seem to work here.

I am sure someone has had dotnet docker to docker communication, it must be pretty common, so maybe the wisdom of the crowd could help a lost soul here?

Comment: Last June Microsoft did a security update and disables TLS 1.0 and 1.1 on servers. So you must use TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3. SSL is even older and is also disable. Many application still give a SSL error message meaning either SSL or TLS. So any old code may not work. Make sure you use a new version of docker that supports TLS 1.2. then depending on version of Net some encryption algorithms may not work. The best solution is to use Net 4.7.2 or later which has option to use Operating System for TLS instead of Net. Microsoft is better at updating encryption in Windows than in Net

Comment: In this case I cannot use .NET Framework, we have Linux containers.

Comment: I said Operating System.  You also may need to update the kernel to get newer encryption algorithms to work.

Answer (score -1):

The dotnet development certificates only work when they are accessed as localhost. Container to container communication is therefore not supported.

So unfortunately there is no easy fix.

One work-around is to create your own CA cert and service certificates, tell Kestrel to use these certs instead of the default dev certs, and have every service trust your CA cert. There is some more info on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/5733#issuecomment-674293641).